# В react-dnd при старте перетаскивания делается снимок элемента с прокруткой

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-n-drop

Проблема с реализацией Drag&Drop при помощи react-dnd.
Если у перетаскиваемого элемента имеется скролл, и в элементе только текстовое содержимое, то preview элемента делается правильно, без скрытой части.
Но как-только я добавляю внизу input например, то в начале перетаскивания делается снимок элемента, а так же области которая скрыта.

Вот пример данной проблемы на codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-https-kvmc8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Пример не добавлен все таки

Comment: Пример добавил.